# Why when drawing rectangles over image inside pictureBox sometimes it's showing the old drawn rectangles when clicking the mouse down?

Tags: c#, winforms

The project can be found here: https://github.com/chocolade1972/Images-Crop

The mouse events on pictureBox2 when i draw the rectangles :

mouse down

```
private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;

            if (pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != null)
            {
                DrawingRects.Add(new DrawingRectangle()
                {
                    Location = e.Location,
                    Size = Size.Empty,
                    StartPosition = e.Location,
                    Owner = (Control)sender,
                    DrawingcColor = SelectedColor // <= Shape's Border Color
                });
            }
        }
```

mouse move

```
private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int X = e.X;
        int Y = e.Y;

        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;

        if ((X >= 0 && X <= pictureBox2.Width) && (Y >= 0 && Y <= pictureBox2.Height))
        {
            if (pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != null)
            {
                x = e.X;
                y = e.Y;

                var dr = DrawingRects[DrawingRects.Count - 1];
                if (e.Y < dr.StartPosition.Y) { dr.Location = new Point(dr.Rect.Location.X, e.Y); }
                if (e.X < dr.StartPosition.X) { dr.Location = new Point(e.X, dr.Rect.Location.Y); }

                dr.Size = new Size(Math.Abs(dr.StartPosition.X - e.X), Math.Abs(dr.StartPosition.Y - e.Y));
                pictureBox2.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
```

mouse up

```
    private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;

            if (DrawingRects.Count > 0 && pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != null)
            {
                var dr = DrawingRects.Last();
                if (dr.Rect.Width > 0 && dr.Rect.Height > 0)
                {
                    rectImage = cropAtRect((Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image, dr.Rect);
                    if (saveRectangles)
                    {
                        rectangleName = GetNextName(Path.Combine(selectedPath, "Rectangle"), ".bmp"); 
                        FileList.Add($"{dr.Location}, {dr.Size}", rectangleName);
                        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    FileList,
    Formatting.Indented
);
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(selectedPath, "rectangles.txt"), false))
                        {
                            sw.Write(json);
                            sw.Close();
                        }

                        rectImage.Save(rectangleName);
                        saveRectanglesCounter++;
                    }
                    pixelsCounter = rect.Width * rect.Height;

                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();

                    listBox1.DataSource = FileList.ToList();
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;

                    pictureBox2.Focus();
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.pictureBox1.Image);
                    g.Clear(this.pictureBox1.BackColor);
                }
            }
        }
```

picturebox2 paint event

```
private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBox2.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

            if (pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != null)
            {
                if ((x >= 0 && x <= pictureBox2.Image.Size.Width) && (y >= 0 && y <= pictureBox2.Image.Size.Height))
                {
                    DrawShapes(e.Graphics);
                }
            }
        }
```

picturebox1 paint event

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (drawBorder)
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
            }

            if (rectImage != null && DrawingRects.Count > 0)
            {
                var dr = DrawingRects.Last();
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(rectImage, dr.Rect);

                if (clearRectangles)
                {
                    DrawingRects.Clear();
                    pictureBox2.Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
```

in the picturebox1 paint event the flag clearRectangles is set to false i set it in the constructor just to test the problem.

then i draw on image in the picturebox2 some rectangles when i try to draw a rectangle outside the image area not the picturebox area but the image area it's deleting all the rectangles but i don't want it to be deleted because the flag clearRectangles is false.

the second problem is after trying to draw outside the image area and it's deleting all the rectangles when then again clicking with the mouse on the image it's showing the drawn rectangles including this i tried to draw outside the image area.

- if the flag clearRectangles is false don't delete the rectangles at all and don't allow to draw outside the image area.
- if the flag clearRectangles is true each time when drawing a rectangle it's deleting the rectangle and when clicking the image again after trying to draw outside the image area it should not showing all the drawn rectangles.

[drawn rectangles after trying to draw outside the image area and then clicking on the image to draw again and it's showing the older drawn rectangles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttl5w.jpg)